# Why is Chart.JS linking my start and end nodes in the line chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to plot my data on a Chart.JS line chart and it is producing a line between the start and end nodes. What can I do to prevent this?

**Current JavaScript code:**

```
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            fill: false,
                            label: "# of Players",
                            data: tdata,

                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                type: "time",
                                display: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: "Date",
                                },
                                time: {
                                    unit: "day",
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

[image: Chart.JS line]

Comment: Probably you need to sort your tdata object according to time variable. If I can see the data I can help more.

Comment: Thanks @cbalakus, I've sorted the tdata array and it now appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved question by sorting my tdata array by date.

```
tdata.sort(function(a,b){
        return new Date(a.x) - new Date(b.x)
})
```